# Trying pass String argument while creating bean Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean defined like following..
context is autowired..

```java
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
 ... 
RabbitQueue queue = (RabbitQueue) context.getBean("rabbitQueue");
QueueName queueNameTest = (QueueName) context.getBean("QueueName", "audittesting");
```

This queueNameTest will be passed to another bean creation as argument..

```java
Queue q1= queue.createQueue(queueNameTest);
```

This createQueue bean definition is like..

```
@Bean
public Queue createQueue(QueueName queueName) {
    String strQueueName = queueName.getQueueName();
    logger.info("Created rabbitmq queue {}", strQueueName);
    return QueueBuilder
             .durable(strQueueName)
             .withArguments(deadLetterArgs(AuditRabbitMQConstants.DL_ROUTING_KEY))
             .build();
    }
```

now in the QueueName class I have ..

```
@Component
public class QueueName {
    private String arg;

    public QueueName(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
    public String getQueueName()
    {
        return arg;
    }
}
```

when i am trying to run .. i am getting

```
n***************************nAPPLICATION FAILED TO STARTn***************************nDescription:nParameter 0 of constructor in com.rabbitmq.QueueName required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.nAction:nConsider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.n"}
```

Basically i need to pass a argument to createQueue() dynamically during runtime..
how do I achive this ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Why is `createQueue(...)` marked as bean creation method if it 
 is called programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to programmatically create a bean

try the following

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)context;
SingletonBeanRegistry beanRegistry = configContext.getBeanFactory();

Queue myQueue = createQueue("myString");
beanRegistry.registerSingleton("queue", myqueue);

//remove @bean from here it will not be created automatically
//keep the method to create bean programmaticaly
public Queue createQueue(QueueName queueName) {
    String strQueueName = queueName.getQueueName();
    logger.info("Created rabbitmq queue {}", strQueueName);
    return QueueBuilder.durable(strQueueName)
            .withArguments(deadLetterArgs(AuditRabbitMQConstants.DL_ROUTING_KEY))
            .build();
}

//Remove @Component from here it will not be created automatically
public class QueueName {
```

If somewhere you have

```
@Autowired
Queue queue
```

then make it

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
Queue queue
```

as it will be lazily initialized.

**Edit:** As per comment asked here is how you can register prototype beans dynamically

If you are on Spring 5 or later you can use `GenericApplicationContext`

```
public yourClass {

   @Autowired
   private GenericApplicationContext context;

   public Queue registerQueue(QueueName queueName) {
    String strQueueName = queueName.getQueueName();
    logger.info("Created rabbitmq queue {}", strQueueName);
    
     context.registerBean(queueName, Queue.class, ()-> 
               QueueBuilder.durable(strQueueName) 
            .withArguments(deadLetterArgs(AuditRabbitMQConstants.DL_ROUTING_KEY))
            .build() );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this..
beanRegistry.registerSingleton("queue", myqueue);

here is it possible to make ti prototype one ? 
i mean the createqueue will be called multiple time with different queue names.
so there we need prototype .. right ?

Comment: @Baitanik check my updated answer for your request